# Reverse the order of a stacked bar graph - while highlighting in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# Create the data
library(tidyverse)
dat <- read.table(text = "A B C
                          1   23  234 324
                          2   34  534 12
                          3   56  324 124
                          4   34  234 124
                          5   123 534 654",
                  sep = "", 
                  header = TRUE) %>% 
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value") %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(ind = as.factor(rep(1:5)), 
         perc = value / sum(value)) %>% 
  arrange(variable, -perc) %>% 
  mutate(ordering = row_number())

# Plot the data
ggplot(dat, aes(variable, perc, fill = interaction(
  -ordering, variable))  # line #20
  ) + 
  geom_col(color = "white", size = 1.5, alpha = 0.25) + 
  facet_grid(~ variable, scales = "free_x") + 
  scale_fill_manual("ind", values = rep("black", length(dat$variable))) + 
  geom_col(data = dat %>% filter(ordering == 1),
           color = "white",
           size = 1.5,
           fill = "red",
           alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image: highlight stacked bar graph]

I've got my highlighted, faceted, stacked bar graph above. I want to reverse the order of everything so I change `-ordering` on line #20 to `ordering`. That gives me this graph below.

[image: highlighted stacked bar graph reverse]

You can see that my line #20 change did indeed reverse the order of the grey sections of this stacked bar graph. But the red highlights remain on the bottom of the graph when I want them to flip to the top of the graph.

How do I achieve this? I tried the answer in many similar SO questions of adding `position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE))` to both of my `geom_col()` and to each separately, but these three new attempts didn't work either. I got the same plot as shown directly above.

Comment: @Mike changing the ordering to `geom_col(data = dat %>% filter(ordering == 5), color = "white", size = 1.5, fill = "red", alpha = 0.5)` does not work either. That highlights the bottom section of the 'reverse' A and B facets. But not C at all (weird). So it's totally wrong. But also the first thing I thought to try. I should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a similar but differently coded approach which includes a scale for *alpha* as well. The idea is to leave `dat` untouched but to set-up manual scales for `fill` and `alpha`. `ordering` is used directly; no need to call `interaction()`.

```
red <- 1L
n_ord <- length(unique(dat$ordering))
fill_scale <- c("red", rep("black", n_ord - 1L)) %>% 
  setNames(red * seq(n_ord))
alpha_scale <- c(0.5, rep(0.25, n_ord - 1L)) %>% 
  setNames(red * seq(n_ord))

# Plot the data
ggplot(dat, aes(variable, perc, fill = factor(red * ordering), alpha = factor(red * ordering))) + 
  # ggplot(dat, aes(variable, perc, fill = interaction(
  #   -ordering, variable))  # line #20
  # ) + 
  geom_col(color = "white", size = 1.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(guide = "none", values = fill_scale) + 
  scale_alpha_manual(guide = "none", values = alpha_scale) + 
  facet_grid(~ variable, scales = "free_x") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image]

The manual scales look as follows

```
fill_scale
```

> ```
>       1       2       3       4       5 
>   "red" "black" "black" "black" "black"
> ```

```
alpha_scale
```

> ```
>    1    2    3    4    5 
> 0.50 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
> ```

---

If the variable `red` is toggled, i.e., `red <- -1L`, we can reproduce OP's original plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the interaction also in defining a variable and solve the problem in the following way:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(fill_breaks = as.character(interaction(-ordering, variable)), 
         fill_values = if_else(ordering == 1, "red", "black"))

fill_values <- dat$fill_values
names(fill_values) <- dat$fill_breaks


ggplot(dat, aes(variable, perc, fill = fill_breaks)) +
  geom_col(color = "white", size = 1.5, alpha = 0.25) +
  facet_grid( ~ variable, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = fill_values) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image]